# inserting large quantity of data into mysql table

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, insert

I need to insert about 400 000 000 rows of test data into the InnoDB table.
Table is quite simple:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tgt` (
  `id_1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_1`,`id_2`),
  KEY `id_1` (`id_1`),
  KEY `id_2` (`id_2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Data is coming from another table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `src` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  # skip some columns
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I need to insert into tgt all possible combinations  of different ids from table src, so naive method is to execute:

```
INSERT INTO tgt (id_1, id_2) (SELECT  a.id,  b.id FROM `src` a INNER JOIN src b  WHERE a.id <> b.id)
```

And, of course it take  hours or even days... So I am searching for a faster method of doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Dump the source data into a file:

  ```
  SELECT  a.id,  b.id INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt' FROM `src` a INNER JOIN src b  WHERE a.id <> b.id
  ```
- Tune MySQL for large writes:

  ```
  innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
  innodb_log_file_size=2G
  ```

[See how to change the log size](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/07/09/how-to-change-innodb_log_file_size-safely/)

- Start a pipe to split results.txt in chunks

  ```
  pt-fifo-split --lines 1000000 /tmp/result.txt
  ```

  (pt-fifo-split is a part of [Percona Toolkit](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit))
- Load the dump

  ```
  while [ -e /tmp/pt-fifo-split ]; do mysql -u <user> -p<pass> -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/pt-fifo-split' INTO TABLE tgt" <tgt db>; done
  ```

  (if you have problem with "File '/tmp/pt-fifo-split' not found", try  [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215231/load-data-infile-error-code-13) )

Comment: Thanks, it works (after few adjustements). Also, innodb_log_file_size doesn't worked for me (mysql  5.5.37 on ubuntu 14.04)